# jQuery dynamically output variables contents

Tags: jquery

I will trim this down to make it as simple as possible. I have a variable named `car` and another one named `car_output`. Let's say `value = 'car'` and `car_output = 'I like to drive my car'`

So, I'm trying to get the contents of `car_output` placed inside a div `div#car`:

```
$('#'+value).html(value+'_output');
```

This shows within the div `div#car` the actual word "car_output" and not what the variable's contents are (I like to drive my car).

How can I get the variable's contents to be placed inside `div#car`?

`

Comment: you can't do that.... what you can do is instead of creating variables create a key value pair and use bracket notation to fetch dynamic keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a "dynamic" variable in javascript you can access it from the window object, like this:

```
val = "test";
test_output = "Testing completed";

out = window[val + "_output"];
alert(out);
```

this will echo "Testing completed"

Comment: and the fiddle to test ==> http://jsfiddle.net/EF59p/

Answer (score 0):

this does it

```
$( '#' + value ).html( eval( value + '_output' ) );
```

**Sample**

```
var value      = 'car';
var car_output = 'I like to drive my car';

$( '#' + value ).html( eval( value + '_output' ) );
```

you just have to `eval()` your code before

see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z364J/)**

Comment: Depending on how value is populated runing eval could be quite dangerous.